# Github Oauth token for Golang

Tags: github, go, oauth, aws-code-deploy

We use AWS code deploy to deploy the Github projects to Ec2 instances every time it deploys it asks for Github username and password to download the repository. Found following ways to solve this

1. Supply Uname & Pwd (not preferred)
2. Setup SSH Key (not possible as the instance keeps changing ip)
3. Oauth token

Setting up Oauth for PHP repository was done by adding it in composer auth.json *.composer/auth.json*.

```
{
    "http-basic": {},
    "github-oauth": {"github.com": "xyzasasasauhu"}
}
```

But couldn't find a way to do this for Golang project. Typically we want to achieve *go get https://github.com/username/reponame* without supplying the credentials explicitly.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Colleagues in the project facing the same issue.

Comment: Is it a  private repo?

Comment: @ltachi, are you using `go get xxx` ? Did you try this?https://gist.github.com/shurcooL/6927554

Comment: @holys This involves creating SSH key with the instance. So if instance goes down and comes up with new ip another SSH key is required. If it is auth token i can write a start up script to install it right. Also -u doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ltachi  Does this do any help for you ？https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10791

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Don't deploy code. Go is a statically compiled programming language. There's no need to have Go source code on the server you intend to run the Go program on.
2. Don't use `go get` to get the code for your private GitHub repo. As long as the code ends up in the correct subdirectory (`$GOPATH/src/github.com/org/project`), Go doesn't care how it got there. Simply add to your build script a few commands:

   ```
   DIR=$GOPATH/src/github.com/org/project
   TOKEN=yourtoken

   if [ -d $DIR ]; then
     cd $DIR
     git reset --hard  
     git clean -dfx
   else
     mkdir -p $DIR
     cd $DIR
     git init  
   fi

   git pull https://$TOKEN@github.com/org/project.git
   ```